# How to make HttpWebRequest async

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, .net-4.5

I have such code:

```
private async Task<string> Request(url)
    {
        Task<string> task = null;

        try
        {
            task = MakeAsyncRequest(url, "text/html");
            return await task;
        }

        catch
        {
            return null;
        }            
    } 

private async Task<string> MakeAsyncRequest(string url, string contentType)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.ContentType = contentType;
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        request.Timeout = 20000;
        request.Proxy = null;
        Task<WebResponse> task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(
        request.BeginGetResponse,
        asyncResult => request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult),
        (object)null);

            //issue here:
        return await task.ContinueWith(t => ReadStreamFromResponse(t.Result));
    }

private string ReadStreamFromResponse(WebResponse response)
    {
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            //Need to return this response 
            string strContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
            return strContent;
        }
    }
```

I am calling `Request(url)` in `foreach` loop

```
foreach(var url in myUrlList)
{
  string body = Request(method).Result;
}
```

But for some reason the code getting stacked at `return await task.ContinueWith(t => ReadStreamFromResponse(t.Result));` and just freezing.

Is there a better way of doing this or may be some one can explain what is happening? 
I am not getting any errors just something wrong with the `await`....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [call to `Result` in your `foreach` loop is causing a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), as I explain on my blog. In summary, `await` will capture a "context" (e.g., a UI context), and use that to resume the `async` method. Some contexts (e.g., the UI context) only allow one thread in the context. So if you block that special thread (e.g., the UI thread) by calling `Result`, then the `async` method cannot resume execution within that context.

So, the solution is to change your `foreach` loop:

```
foreach(var url in myUrlList)
{
  string body = await ProcessAsync(method);
}
```

Other notes:

Task-returning methods should end in "Async" to follow the [TAP guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).

`Task.Factory.FromAsync` is unnecessary; `HttpWebRequest` already has awaitable methods. An even better option is to use `HttpClient` instead.

I recommend that you not use `Task.ContinueWith` (or `Task.Result`, or `Task.Wait`); use `await` instead.

With these simplifications in place:

```
private async Task<string> MakeAsyncRequestAsync(string url, string contentType)
{
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
  request.ContentType = contentType;
  request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
  request.Timeout = 20000;
  request.Proxy = null;
  WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
  return ReadStreamFromResponse(response);
}
```

This code could be simplified further if you change `HttpWebRequest` to `HttpClient`.

Comment: Just made an edit: `string body = Process(method).Result;` => `string body = Request(method).Result;` Should I change the method `Request(..)` ?

Comment: Yes, but the core problem is still the `Result` call. You should use `await` instead of `Result`.