# Validating Large Number of URLs and Adding Results to ListBox Freezes UI

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, listbox, system.net

I'm validating a set of URLs. When the URL count reaches 30,000 the program's performance deteriorates.

```
Parallel.ForEach(urilist, line =>
{
    if (!IsHttpStatusOk(line.ToString()))
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(line.ToString());
    }
});

public static bool IsHttpStatusOk(string url)
{
    try
    {

        var request = WebRequest.Create(finalurl) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36";
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            return (response as HttpWebResponse).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I need to Display Invalid URLs to the user, for this purpose I use a `ListBox`. This works fine to an extent until the Number of Invalid URLs exceeds some limit. The UI Freezes, the CPU Usage Spikes and the program Becomes non-responsive.

How can i solve this issue? The issue also exists with a `DataGridView` and occurs with a lesser number of URLs..

Comment: You could collect all the data into a list (or filter the one you have?) and then use it as a datasource

Comment: @CalC The final result will be written to an Output File..I have not counted it... Will test again and get back...

Comment: @CalC How to use Async ?

Comment: @Plutonix Will that help with UI Freezing and CPU Load.

Comment: How many items are in the ListBox when performance drops off (only gets added to if status != OK)? When you say "when url count reaches 30,000", do you mean when the number of non-OK requests reaches 30,000? What do your memory & CPU look like when performance degrades? And is ListBox the right control? Are users really scrolling through 30,000+ items and selecting from that list?

Comment: @techno See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171928/how-to-make-httpwebrequest-async#22173286

Comment: UI Freezing: yes, somewhat - the controls have to repaint every time you add a thing.  Using a DataSource sets them all at once.  *Processing* (parallel vs async etc) is something else

Comment: @pep The Number of items in the ListBox is 577..I have tried with a Binding List and the same issue...

Comment: @CalC The Number of items in the ListBox is 577.